# Angular input/buttons not animating

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to create a login page, but the angular buttons and inputs are not animating as on https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview and https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview

My code is located on https://stackblitz.com/github/vibhorgoyal18/atest-blog
and the route to the login page is /login

Please help me resolving this.

Also when I click Sign up and back to loogin, it shows a scrollbar for a second. Please advice on that too

login.html

```
     <div class="container align-content-center py-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
          <mat-tab-group disableRipple>
            <mat-tab label="Login">
              <mat-card>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center py-3">
                    <mat-form-field>
                      <input matInput placeholder="username">
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center py-3">
                    <mat-form-field floatLabel="always">
                      <input matInput>
                    </mat-form-field>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center py-3">
                    <button mat-button>Login</button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </mat-card>
            </mat-tab>
            <mat-tab label="Sign Up">
              <mat-card><div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center py-3">
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="username">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center py-3">
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="email">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center py-3">
                  <mat-form-field>
                    <input matInput placeholder="password">
                  </mat-form-field>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12 align-content-center py-3">
                  <button mat-button>Login</button>
                </div>
              </div></mat-card>
            </mat-tab>
          </mat-tab-group>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

and app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

    import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
    import {HeaderComponent} from './modules/main/header/header.component';
    import {LoginComponent} from './modules/login/login.component';
    import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
    import {
      MatButtonModule,
      MatCardModule,
      MatDialogModule,
      MatFormFieldModule, MatInputModule,
      MatTabsModule
    } from '@angular/material';
    import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
    import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeaderComponent,
        LoginComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        MatTabsModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        MatCardModule,
        MatFormFieldModule,
        MatInputModule,
        MatButtonModule
      ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule {
    }
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve] in your question, and not just link to your code, links tend to die over time and then this question becomes just useless for anyone else ;)

Comment: Don't get me wrong, links to actual working code is a great addition, "addition" being the keyword ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to styles.css
and add this to the top

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Comment: how to import this in my style.sass? I already have an import for bootstrap and when I add this it complains. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import matButtonModule:

```
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';
```

Comment: Sorry, but importing the suggested import did not worked